# Change content of div to many text fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the content of div through javascript, but not just to one paragraph.suppose if I have three to four paragraphs,the text field should keep changing,with effect. I have written this code,but it changes only one paragraph.Its not changing again.It would also be good if it were depicted like the letter falls and content is in next letter.Please help

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("paraone").innerHTML="<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left'>Hello World!</marquee>";
      }
    </script>

    <style>
      body {
        background: linear-gradient(#ccc, #fff);
        font: 14px sans-serif;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      .letter {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        margin: 26px auto 0;
        max-width: 550px;
        min-height: 300px;
        padding: 24px;
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
      }
      .letter:before, .letter:after {
        content: "";
        height: 98%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
      .letter:before {
        background: #fafafa;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        left: -5px;
        top: 4px;
        transform: rotate(-2.5deg);
      }
      .letter:after {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        right: -3px;
        top: 1px;
        transform: rotate(1.4deg);
      }
    </style>
    <body>

      <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Click</button>
      <div class="letter">

        <p>Dear Friends,</p>
        <p id="paraone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing     elit. Praesent euismod porta tempor. Donec pulvinar turpis nec velit pellentesque quis rhoncus sapien facilisis. Mauris quis massa dui,onvallis est pretium.</p>
     </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen? What's happening?

Comment: When i click the button the text Hello world comes.But what if it is like a birthday events,when i click it should show the forthcoming birthdays right?I want to do it like that,but i am able to show only one change of div

Comment: No idea what you want. Your JS refers to the paragraph with the ID - therefore only this one paragraph will be changed.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You are showing that you can indeed change the content of a paragraph with JavaScript. What is the main point of your question? You can have multiple paragraphs, and you can write logic in the JavaScript to choose different values to insert as content.

Comment: Yea i want that,to insert one para everytime i click.To make the question clear enough,lets say its a event manager kind of thing.After each event,when i click,the next event should come in the same div,and after that event,when i click,the next event,and so on.

Comment: @ManojKSharma Still we can't understand what you actually need.

Comment: A calendar,on each click should flip to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear - but I *think* your aim is to *append* text, rather than replace.

```
document.getElementById("paraone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("paraone").innerHTML + "<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left'>Hello World!</marquee>";
```

This will set the innerHTML of the element to "the inner HTML of the element, AND `<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left'>Hello World!</marquee>`. It pretty much says, "set it to what is it at the moment, PLUS .....".

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/756yxaqh/

This approach isn't ideal - the marquee, for example, will be reset each time you append something new, as the entire content of the element is being replaced. A better way would be to insert a *new element* in the div.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left'>Hello World!</marquee>";
document.getElementById("paraone").appendChild(p);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/756yxaqh/1/

BTW, if you're just starting out with JavaScript, it is worth being aware of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). The second code snippet could be written as:

```
$('#paraone').append('<marquee behaviour="scroll" direction="left">Hello World!</marquee>');
```

Comment: Sir,This is ok,but it should replace the text on every click

Comment: @Manoj Then your current code should do that as it is? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/756yxaqh/2/)

Comment: Sir,to make it simple,it must be like an event widget,on click next event should display,replacing the former event